# Javascript / CSS Not working properly with firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I don't know if it's the row class from bootstrap thats not working, or if it's my JS/CSS that will not load properly with Firefox.. it works with Chrome and Safari. Any thoughts?

Comment: Share your relevant code, rather than the link.

Comment: I don't know what the relevant code is.

Comment: If you don't know what the relevant code is, how do you expect to be able to fix and understand the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try giving the li that the doors are in a width.

ul.enlarge li{

display: inline-block;
margin: 5px 10px 0;
position: relative;
width: 40px;
z-index: 0;
}

Answer (score 0):

On line 122 of style.css you have:

```
.portfolio-images img {
    width: 300px;
}
```

What's that for?  If you remove it, it works OK in Firefox.

**UPDATE**:
My mistake - if you update it to width:100% it works OK in Firefox.